# ¿Cómo cargar un archivo de 5gb en un byte array en java?

Tags: java, c#

Estoy implementando un cliente y un servidor Rest. El servidor lo implemente en C# y el cliente lo estoy implementando en java. Al momento de querer subir un archivo superior a 2GiB el cliente se muere. ¿Existe alguna forma para convertir un archivo más grande (5GiB sería lo ideal) en un byte array para enviarlo al servidor?

Lo que intenté fue lo siguiente:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Path path2 = Paths.get(path + nombreArchivo);
byte[] bytesArchivo = Files.readAllBytes(path2);
ByteArrayEntity byteEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(bytesArchivo);

HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri);
post.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader);
post.setEntity(byteEntity);
```

Pero en la segunda linea, al querer todo los bytes muere.

La razón por la cual lo hago de esta manera, es porque no puedo ni requiero enviar metadatos en el entity, solo el archivo como tal, si envío metadatos, entonces cambia el tamaño del body, causando conflictos al momento de querer recuperar el archivo ya que su peso difiere de los metadatos que ya fueron previamente registrados.

Gracias por la atención.

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de intentar cargar los 5GB en memoria, usa lo siguiente:

```
File file = new File(path + nombreArchivo)
MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
mpEntity.addPart("userfile", cbFile);
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri);
post.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader);
post.setEntity(mpEntity);
```

Comment: Lo que sucede es que con esta clase, se envían metadatos y datos. Yo solo requiero enviar los datos (es decir, el archivo únicamente), sin ningún metadato. La razón por la cual no quiero metadatos es que antes de enviar el archivo hago un registro del mismo en el servidor enviando los metadatos antes. Si lo envio con MultipartEntity, se añaden metadatos al body que al procesarlos, cambian el tamaño del archivo al especificado en los metadatos provocando inconsistencia.